# If Start Date is populated then status cannot be Not Started

Tags: validation, validation-rule

If Start date or End date is populated then status cannot be Not Started

```
AND(ISPICKVAL( Status__c , 'Not Started'), ISBLANK( Start_Date__c ))
```

Comment: Please take a moment to visit the [help], scroll through the [tour], and read [ask]. This post does not even contain a question. What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: So what is not working about what you have so far?

Comment: Should maybe work when you add a not to start date check, here is an example- `AND(ISPICKVAL( Status__c , 'Not Started'), NOT(ISBLANK( Start_Date__c )))`

Answer (score 1):

You need to validate both dates:

```
AND(
 ISPICKVAL( Status__c , 'Not Started'),
 NOT(
 AND(
  ISBLANK( Start_Date__c ),
  ISBLANK( End_Date__c )
 )
 )
)
```